# publishing paid app using flavor variant

Tags: android

i want to publish a paid app and free app
i have created flavor of free and paid using this code

```
 productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.free"
        versionName "1.0-free"
        // this boolean can be accessed in java classes by using BuildConfig class
        // and now you can identify if your app is the paid version or not
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
    }

    paid {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.paid"
        versionName "1.0-paid"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"
    }
}
```

I want to know how can upload this app 
we need two diffretnt apk for that (paid relese apk and free apk)
or single apk

i need both variant available in playstore

Answer (score 0):

You got this type of Build variant as shown in image: In your case you can see paidDebug and freeDebug option.

If you want to release paid version then you have to select paidDebug and if you want to release free version then you have to select freeDebug.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , after changes like you said  ... we need only one apk upload as paid???/

Answer (score 0):

If You have two flavor variant

like

1. Free with package name as

   applicationId "com.example.myapp.free"
2. Paid with package name as

   applicationId "com.example.myapp.paid"

Both are different applicationId so you need to upload in two different apps in play store, Because your applicationId is a playstore app id So it must be a unique

or

You have to remove this line in both flavor and use common applicationId

then

handle like this following way

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
}    
productFlavors {
    free {
        versionName "1.0-free"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
        buildConfigField "String", "BuildType", "Free"
    }

    paid {
        versionName "1.0-paid"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"
        buildConfigField "String", "BuildType", "Paid"
    }
}
```

**Handle in java code**

```
public void manageFeaturesWithBuildType()
    {
        String buildType = BuildConfig.BuildType;
        if(buildType.equals("Paid"))
        {
            //Here Enable or Disable your features for paid Build
        }
        else
        {
            //Here Enable or Disable your features for free Build
        }
    }
```

Comment: which mode and version are need on making sign apk.. freedebeug orer paid deug???